# Predicting JavaCard applet size on card

Tags: javacard

When I "Clean and Build" a JavaCard project, it produces a CAP, EXP and JCA file. Typically, the CAP file would be used by tools like the GlobalPlatformPro or other GlobralPlatform toolkits to for installing CAP files into a JavaCard.

I noticed that my CAP file is hovering around 44KB of size while my JCA is 82 KB. Between CAP and JCA file, which one should I use to guage the size of my codes most accurately ?

Comment: I know that the JCOP tools display the size on the card as well as the upload size. However, that may be specific to their platform as the actual storage size may differ (somewhat). Presumably the byte code size will be identical on most platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPPro will show the code size with `-cap file.cap -info`

Comment: Could you add a sample output of this command? I would like to have some idea of the output without actually  executing it myself; I think others would too.

Comment: Just an additional question, if I were to import other EXP files and other JAR file libraries, will that also be counted to the total code size in since it says 5242 bytes and 17345 with debug ? Also, on Windows File System view, the CAP file says test.cap is 44 KB in size. So, do I take 5242 bytes reported as actual size on card or 17345 bytes (with debug) on card or 44 KB from Windows view ?

Comment: The CAP file is a (usually uncompressed) .zip file. Have a look into it to have some more ideas what is send to the card. Not all .cap files have to be send though (mainly debug.cap), and not all data has to be stored either.

Answer (score 2):

JCA (Java Card Assembly) is the textual representation of the CAP file.

A CAP file is a container file and each component in this container is a file in itself. It contains the information about the converted package where each component contains the information about the converted package. This file will be use to a GP client (or something similar) to load the byte-code (in cap file) to the card.

If you're converting an applet for eventual installation onto a smart card, you can generate a CAP file and a JCA file. You can then examine the JCA file to check the content in CAP file in a user friendly readable manner.

So,

> which one should I use to guage the size of my codes most accurately ?

Relatively speaking, the size of both the files (CAP & JCA) would change with any change in the source code, but you can check the CAP file size for this purpose.

More information about CAP & JCA can be found from.
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/documentation/applet-136808.html#capfl

Answer (score 0):

Replying to @Martin Paljak, here's the GPPro output:

```
GlobalPlatformPro v0.3.10rc4-0-gb81610e
Running on Windows 7 ..... , Java 1.8.0_151 by Oracle Corporation
**** CAP info of test.cap
CAP file (v2.2) generated on Fri Jan 18 ......... 2019
By Oracle Corporation converter  [v3.0.4] with JDK 1.8.0 (Oracle Corporation)
Package: ..... v1.0 with AID ..........
Applet: ..... with AID ..........
Import: A0000000620001 v1.0
Import: A0000000620102 v1.5
Import: A0000000620201 v1.5
Import: A0000000620101 v1.5
Total code size: 5242 bytes (17345 with debug)
SHA256 (code): 2AC53C69054C0B33BC2814A514A60BDE8B4E084FC2136AB562492D54A55C1129
SHA1   (code): B523BF8E49C86157988FD1BDD667E4CC68CFF8EF
No smart card readers with a card found
```

Comment: OK, cool. I presume this is the upload code size though; the required flash / EEPROM may be lower for the code itself and - of course - possibly higher after instantiating the Applets themselves (because class fields will be stored in persistent memory too). And, as indicated before, the precise amount of memory required on chip is also specific to the platform - the amount of meta data is not known and platforms may make e.g. different decisions about memory alignment. Note that it is more accepted to edit this into the answer of Martin instead of posting it separately.